# Why do I have to use getSupportActionBar() for activity that extends AppCompatActivity?

Tags: java, android

Hello I am not so sure why I am getting error when I use `getActionBar().setTitle("test")` but when I use  `getSupportActionBar().setTitle("test")`, everything works fine. So I did some research and found that I have to use `getSupportActionBar()` for activity that extends `AppCompatActivity`.

1. I am not so sure why this is the case and would like an explanation?
2. Why can't I just `import android.app.ActionBar` and then use `getActionBar()` (I have tried this and use the `setTitle()` method. It returns `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference`) ?

I am well aware of the existence of `Toolbar` but I want to use `ActionBar` for backward compatibility.

Comment: Of course, [Toolbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) works back to API 7, same as `AppCompatActivity`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. AppCompatActivity is activity for older version android up to latest version. so if your targer application is android 2.3 - 6.0 you must extend appcompactactivity rather than just plain activity. and method getActionBar is intended to use with activity. getSupportActionBar is intended to use with appCompactActivity
2. What you import is a class from other project, not the actual object that has been initialized in your activity. and in your activity you dont initialized the class that you import, and then it becomes NPE ( Null Pointer Exception )

Answer (score 1):

Using `AppCompatActivity` instead of `ActionBarActivity` is proper way. Normal usage is deprecated, since `AppCompatActivity` provides backward compatibility, which you want.

You should not aware of `Toolbar`, because `Toolbar` is fully supported in `AppCompat` and has feature and API parity with the framework widget. In `AppCompat`, `Toolbar` is implemented in the `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` class.

Some references for you:

- [ActionBar documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html)
- [Android Developers blog about AppCompat](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)

Answer (score 0):

The logic is action bar is used pre material design and toolbaar is used post material design.

Both of them doesn't coexist.I meant you can't use action bar in post material design era.

Either you can compare the device version and switch accordingly or simple use supportedtoolbar which does it internally for you.

Comment: Thanks for answering but I am not using a tool bar because in both cases I call getActionBar() not getToolBar() so I don't think it is post material design.